# Use an operator overloader in an operator overloading function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following class (in C++):

```
class Card
{
public:
    //other functions

    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os)
    {
        if (rank < 11) os << rank;
        else if (rank == 11) os << "J";
        else if (rank == 12) os << "Q";
        else if (rank == 13) os << "K";
        else os << "A";

        switch (suit)
        {
        case 0:
                os << char (6);
            break;
        case 1:
            os << char (3);
            break;
        case 2:
            os << char (4);
            break;
        case 3:
            os << char (5);
            break;
        }
    }
private:
    Suit suit;
    Rank rank; //these are both pre-defined enums
}
```

And this class:

```
class Hand
{
public:
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os)
    {
        for (std::vector<Card>::iterator iter = cards.begin(); iter < cards.end(); ++iter)
            os << *iter << ", "; //THIS LINE PRODUCES THE ERROR
        return os;
    }
private:
    std::vector<Card> cards;
};
```

However, it produces an error on the line marked. T'm assuming it has to do with the `<<` overloading in the `Card` class. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Define it as a free function, which takes `std::ostream&` as the first parameter and your class as the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot overload insertion into a `ostream` as a member function as the first argument is the `ostream`. You need to make it a free function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Card const &);
```

The operator that you overloaded would have to be called as:

```
Card c;
c << std::cout;
```

Which is quite unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
    Suit suit;
    Rank rank; //these are both pre-defined enums
```

use this  code...